# Angular routing navigation issues with Bootstrap Carousel tabs

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angular, angular-routing

I have created 4 tabs on a page with previous and next elements to traverse through the carousel items.

Each tab is a different page , so each tab has a different URL. When I click on Next, the tab header changes to the next tab but the URL doesnt change. So the content does not get loaded when the tab is changed. Likewise for Previous.

Also I'm using `<router-outlet>`. How do I make the tabs function when I click Next or Previous?

Here is my code

```
<div id="carouselId" class="carousel slide" data-ride="'carousel'" data-interval="false">

  <div class="carousel-inner nav-tabs" role="listbox">
    <div *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let i = index"
  class="carousel-item" routerLinkActive="active">
       <a id="activeHeader" class="nav-link" [routerLink]="[tab.tabRoute]">    {{tab.tabName}}</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    <a class="carousel-control" href="#carouselId" role="button" data-slide="prev"> 
     Previous
    </a>

    <a class="carousel-control" href="#carouselId" role="button" data-slide="next">
     Next
    </a>

<div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Comment: did you get any solution for this?

Comment: @GauravSharma I had to use `hammer js` to implement swipe on touch devices.